# Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.MapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, fragment

I know this question is asked so many times. but not working in my case tried so many solution. so help please

my mainActivity extends Activity within onCreate map generates this way.

```
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

and xml view is

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

support:

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

error em getting:

```
    03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406): Process: com.commteldigital.cinecorn.activity, PID: 26406
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.commteldigital.cinecorn.activity/com.commteldigital.cmovies.activity.LocationActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:305)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1944)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at com.commteldigital.cmovies.activity.LocationActivity.onCreate(LocationActivity.java:27)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    ... 11 more
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:597)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4811)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    ... 21 more
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.MapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.commteldigital.cinecorn.activity-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.commteldigital.cinecorn.activity-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:583)
03-01 13:29:20.089: E/AndroidRuntime(26406):    ... 24 more
```

well. have imported google play lib from extras folder. why the class is unavailable. thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have the target SDK as Google Inc.:Google APIs:21 (or your version number)?

Comment: yes Google Inc.:Google APIs:21

Comment: I think Fahim has a good point

Comment: you need to check my edited ver of question

Comment: Just a check, your project.properties file should look like: target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:21 android.library.reference.1=..\\..\\google-play-services_lib

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are using a wrong name. Use this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
</merge>
```

In addition, `getMap()` is now deprecated, you are using an old API.

Comment: still same error problem is here: Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public

Comment: can you check log please

Comment: Please use my own code if you want to solve your problem. The name used is different so it's not possible that there is the same error, are you kidding me?

Comment: actually i did use same code you posted. but not working in my case. same error

Comment: It's not possible, it means you are not using this code. Try to do a clean and recompile your project and you have to do a check about what kind of layout you are using. I repeat, the name is different, so it's *not* possible to have the same error.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    
</LinearLayout>

Comment: linear layout em using.

Comment: You are still using the wrong name, I don't know how I can say you. COPY my own code please.

Comment: greywolf is right you are using a wrong name in your code it should be `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"` instead of `android:name="com.google.android.gms.MapFragment"`

Comment: @user3819810 In addition, you need to know that stackoverflow is not a free forum, you need to accept the response when you ask something. If you don't accept any answer you won't receive much response in the future.

Comment: thanks. but problem still there, now in log. Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public.... now?

Comment: Are you using eclipse or android studio? It seems to me you are not including Google Play Services library in your project.

Comment: greywolf. please easy. if the problem get fixed, i must accept. but someone should be so polite when helping :(

Comment: eclipse. i did clean recompile as well

Comment: See here and select Eclipse ADT: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: already imported lib project. otherwise eclipse won't let me include this import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

Comment: Ok, then the problem can be your AVD. Are you using the Google system image? If you are using the "plain" system image it doesn't work due to the lack of google play services at runtime. Check your SDK installation.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. You can try to post the eclipse project settings just to see if the inclusion of google play services is setup in the right way as you can see here: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

Comment: this is problem. It setup very perfect as in link :(

Comment: Have you compiled your google play services lib project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71976/discussion-between-user3819810-and-greywolf82).

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

to

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

add those lines in your manifest files within `application` tag if you didn't add them

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: yes already there. if not should be in log. as i posted. can you please read the complete error. it is something not allowing to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.MapFragment

Comment: Please check if the google play services library is imported correctly. may be this is the problem.

Comment: imported from sdk extras folder. and there is no error... what more to be sure?